# Can't run camera_uvc package on jade

Tags: ros, catkin, camera, source, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I had a problem building and running the http://wiki.ros.org/uvc_camera. I would need a stereo camera driver providing 2 images and 2 camera_info messages on Jade.
I found camrea_uvc, I tried building the camera_uvc from source using this guide: https://defendtheplanet.net/2014/11/05/using-ros-indigo-webcam-by-the-uvc_camera-usb-video-class-package/ , the rosdep install part failed with "missing resource". But if I use catkin_make, it checks the dependencies, right?
Catkin_make is successful: *[100%] B[100%] Built target uvc_stereo_node*. But after i try to launch it, it fails: "ERROR: cannot launch node of type [uvc_camera/camera_node]: can't locate node [camera_node] in package [uvc_camera]" Is this an installation problem? Can you link me some tutorials about building packages from source?
Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221322/can%27t-run-camera_uvc-package-on-jade/) by [master_19](https://answers.ros.org/users/25040/master_19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0